# How to execute Django dispatched signal in view function?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

Info: I want to make app like upload file before submit the form. TusUpload will receive the file data and send signal. if user add multiple files it will send signal multiple time.

I want to execute this signal in `create_page` the ***Example*** code is in the below. The `create_page` function take the files which files signals send by `TusUpload` and saved into the `Attach` model object `post` object also linked.

The `create_page` is just a logic which i want to perform.

I hope you will be able to provide the information.

views.py

```
class TusUpload(View):

    def patch(self, request, resource_id, *args, **kwargs):

        tus_file = TusFile.get_tusfile_or_404(str(resource_id))
        chunk = TusChunk(request)

        if tus_file.is_complete():
            # file transfer complete, rename from resource id to actual filename

            self.send_signal(tus_file)

        return TusResponse(status=204, extra_headers={'Upload-Offset': tus_file.offset})

    def send_signal(self, tus_file):

        tus_upload_finished_signal.send(
            sender=self.__class__,
            metadata=tus_file.metadata,
            file_id=tus_file.resource_id,
            filename=tus_file.filename,
            upload_file_path=tus_file.get_path(),
            file_size=tus_file.file_size,
            upload_url=settings.TUS_UPLOAD_URL,
            destination_folder=settings.TUS_DESTINATION_DIR)
```

signals.py

```
tus_upload_finished_signal = django.dispatch.Signal(
    providing_args=[
        "metadata",
        "file_id",
        "filename",
        "upload_file_path",
        "file_size",
        "upload_url",
        "destination_folder"
    ]
)
```

views.py

```
def create_page(request):
    files = []

    @receiver(tus_upload_finished_signal)
    def create_file(sender, **kwargs):
        filename = kwargs['filename']
        files.append(filename)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.instance.author = request.user
            form.save()

            for f in files:
                attach = Attach()
                attach.file = f
                attach.post=form.instance
                attach.save()

            return redirect('index_page')
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'core/_form.html', context)
```